# why is it a bad practice to inherit every class, and then simply make a single object of derived class to do all operations in oop?

Tags: java, c++, oop, code-reuse

I'm new to c++, i got a simple question to implement a bakery, having products(ex. pastry,donuts) and baking machine to work on those products(calculate calories, baking temperature etc). I just made two classes, wrote all the functions, and then inherited them to make a single class, and did my work but my mentor is not happy with that way. i want to ask what's wrong there? How does it affect code re-usability?? Here are the function prototypes which I made. P.s. I'm new to OOP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <map>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int minimum(vector<int>);
struct Inventory
{
    string Name;
    map<string,float> inputfromfile;
};
class BakedItem
{
public:
    BakedItem(){}
    ~BakedItem() {}

protected:
    string Item;
    float TemperatureForBakingItem;
    vector <string> ShapesPossible;
    vector <string> Ingredients;
    void GetIngredients(string);
    void ShapesPossibility(void);
    void GetTemperature(string);
};
class Bakery:BakedItem
{
public:
    Bakery(){}
    ~Bakery(){}
    time_t * ViewManufactureDate(void);
    float ViewPrice(void);
    void GetInput(string);
    void ViewShapesPossible(void);
protected:
    time_t DateManufacture;
    float PriceOfItem;
    float Calories;
    void GetManufactureDate(void);
    void CalculateCalories(void);
    void CalculatePrice(void);
    void GetInventory(void);
};
```

Comment: What if you want to have a bakery with **two** baked items? Say, donuts and cupcakes? And donuts need to be baked at a different temperature from cupcakes.

Comment: Sure, your program might *work*, but it completely defeats the point of using classes in the first place - if you're going to do this, you might as well make everything global.

Comment: I'm considering only one item at a time, the main function will include a menu inside a while loop to calculate possibilities for other items.

Comment: OOPS should be corrected to OOP (which stands for "object-oriented programming").

Comment: could anyone suggest me a better class design, i generally write my code in c, new to c++

Comment: The way you're doing it creates a new bakery for each type of baked item, which doesn't make sense. Separate the Bakery class into it's own, and then have it create BakedItem objects for each type of baked good. There is no reason to have Bakery as a derived class from BakedItem.

Comment: @AkashSinha If you are familiar with C, you may find it helpful to think of classes as structs with functions attached to them.  Is there any point in creating a `struct Bakery` that has a `float TemperatureForBakedItem` field? Not really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it not only ignores the relationship between different classes, but creates incorrect relationships. Inheritance is an "is-a" relationship. When `Cat` implements `Animal`, the relationship is "Cat is-an Animal".

This is not true for your OOP. `Bakery` should *not* be a `BakedItem`. Rather, a Bakery has zero or more baked items. Otherwise, what does it mean for `Bakery` to have a list of possible shapes? Are we talking floor plans? When you extend a class, the subclass has to abide by the superclasses' contract.

For example, the `BakedItem` class might have a description of:

> This class represents a food item which has been heated in an oven at a specific temperature for a specific amount of time.

If `Bakery` extends `BakedItem`, does that mean that the bakery itself has been put into some giant building-sized oven?

... You can see how following the logical relationships as currently described by your code quickly becomes nonsensical.

---

Remember, fields are a "has-a" relationship, and inheritance represents an "is-a" relationship; Use these to model your objects accurately, because it will make more sense as to what the purpose of each class does and how each method works and interacts with the objects.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i would now go ahead and try to write my code using different class design, this explains a lot, Thanks :)